# Sprites, storing bitmaps in arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

right now i'm using a sheet with all my sprite frames and using a 2 rectangles to take a frame from the sheet and drawing it to a destination rectangle on the canvas. But I was wondering (in terms of speed) if getting every frame at start and storing it in a bitmap array would be better, because it would sure be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert on the subject, but I've been developing a tool that manipulates animated sprites recently.

I certainly see increased animation playback performance if I load all the frames up into a list or array ahead of time. This also allows me to more easily call up a specific frame by index, or do a variety of other things.

I was using a method similar to what you described, and it had two downsides:

1. The source bitmap could not ever be disposed, locking it up from other applications;
2. Larger sprite sheets could not be played back at full speed.

I assume that you'll have a bigger memory footprint if you start storing all the frames instead of just one (but maybe not, since you'd be loading the whole sheet in the other scenario).

I'd love to hear more on the subject from someone with more experience, but I found that I definitely got better results loading all the frames at once.